# Will overall RAM performance be reduced if I use one single ranked RAM stick in one RAM slot and another dual ranked RAM stick in the other slot?

Tags: ramdisk

CPU Z says that my memory is using dual channel, and one slot of RAM is using 8GB dual ranked RAM from Samsung, and the other slot is using 4GB single ranked RAM from crucial. I was just wondering if these differences in the RAM in each slot will reduce overall RAM preformance. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You will not see actual performance differences, if there are any differences, outside of a benchmark environment.  If your memory is in an dual channel configuration you are already in the fastest configuration possible.

Answer (score 0):

Most modern platforms will support asynchronous dual channel setups. Generally the bandwidth performance of your RAM will be the same as in a synchronized setup for the first 8GB and then the last 4GB that will be filled is going to work at half speed.

It is very likely that you will not notice performance differences in real life but this will greatly depend on the platform you're using and the applications you're using. Either way it will perform better than having just one stick of 8GB.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that reply! Just to clarify, you mean that if my RAM usage goes over 8GB the 4GB stick will operate at single channel? To be honest I’m not sure if I should just return the 4GB stick and buy a 4GB dual ranked one since I’ve heard that mixing and matching RAM isn’t a good idea ~

Comment: Close. In dual channel mode the system will divide each chunk of data it writes over the two ram sticks so that in theory the write is twice as fast. When memory use reaches 8GB, stick 1 will be half full while stick 2 is full. At that point the system will only be able to use the free space on one stick to write and thus be only able to write at single channel speed.